# Why do rings form on microwaved CD/DVDs?

Tags: plasma-physics, microwaves

Here's a microwaved CD.
[image: microwaved cd]

As you can see, the disc has been destroyed, but there are very clear circular rings bridged with lines.

Why are rings formed when microwaving discs?

Comment: a guess:  radial expansion plus azimuthal stresses from the manufacturing process?  Try putting one in an oven.

Comment: +1 to the idea for putting it in an oven, I'd be interested to see if this is a question of heating in general or a question of the microwaves specifically

Comment: Did you microwave w/ a rotating turntable? Because if so the answer should be obvious.

Comment: Sorry, my eyes are not the greatest, but is the metal oxidized along the cracks?  I cannot see that happening from a single exposure to heat (unless they hide water under the plastic in CDs).  Second question:  Would the pattern of cracks change if the CD/DVD were empty/blank?  Meaning, do the cracks have anything to do with the content written on the CD/DVD?  The surface is "etched" when written to, so that may help explain the patterns, but the oxidization is funny...